# Javascript for-in loop bizarre behavior

Tags: javascript, for-loop, for-in-loop

Suddenly, I am seeing a strange behavior.
Here is a snippet:

```
// attributesList is an object with properties 0, 1, 2.
for (var j in attributesList) {
   // this loop should run 3 times.
   var attribute = attributesList[j];
}
```

As you can see from above, the loop should run 3 times. But for some very strange reason it is being run 4 times. For the last iteration the value of j == "seek".

Even stranger, this same code base works on another git branch (no changes). This only seems to happen when I run this from a particular git branch.

Is there any logical explanation for this mysterious "seek" property?
One thing I tried looking into is perhaps javascript version and any other versioning differences... but no luck here.

*** Updated ***

attributesList is an array of object type.

Comment: Sure. At some point, that object was given a `seek` property. Try doing a search across your entire code base for `.seek`, `seek:`, `'seek':` or `"seek":`

Comment: @Mike. This was my first thought. But when I evaluate the attributesList during run/debug time I do not see any property called "seek".

Comment: Then either you aren't viewing it correctly, since it clearly has such a property, or it's inherited the property at an earlier point in it's prototype chain that you aren't immediately seeing.

Comment: Re your edit: You ***really*** don't want to add that to your question. It will achieve nothing positive, and in any case, meta content doesn't go in questions. I've removed it for you.

Comment: "attributesList is an array of object type" So is it just an array which contains objects? Or is it an object that you are treating as an array?

Comment: It is literally an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object in question has *four* enumerable properties. It probably inherits `seek` from its prototype object, which is why you think it only has three properties.

Your comment to MikeC adds weight to that:

> when I evaluate the attributesList during run/debug time I do not see any property called "seek"

As does your update:

> attributesList is an array of object type.

That tells us that somewhere in your codebase (probably in a plugin), someone has been very naughty and added an *enumerable* property to `Array.prototype`. They can do that with various different syntaxes; if it's just the one property (`seek`), it's probably like this:

```
Array.prototype.seek = function() {
    // ...
};
```

That's poor practice, they should have made it non-enumerable:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "seek", {
    value: function() {
        // ...
    }
});
```

But fundamentally, `for-in` is not for looping through arrays. See [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) for how to loop through arrays.

Two excerpts from that long answer:

Use `forEach`:

```
attributesList.forEach(function(attribute) {
   // ...
});
```

or if you really want to use `for-in`, add a `hasOwnProperty` check:

```
for (var j in attributesList) {
   if (attributesList.hasOwnProperty(j)) {
      // this loop should run 3 times.
      var attribute = attributesList[j];
   }
}
```

or of course use a `for` loop. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476) for details.

Comment: I thought about using .hasOwnProperty( ). But what if I want to iterate over properties which has been inherited?

Comment: btw, it does looks like "seek" is being inherited. It is actually some kind of built-in function or something.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar: No, JavaScript arrays have no built-in `seek` method.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar: *"what if I want to iterate over properties which has been inherited"* Arrays get no enumerable properties from their prototype by default. It's only when people do silly things such as I called out in my edit just now that they get enumerable properties.

Comment: What is weird is that the object is definitely an array. I am inserting (pushing) objects/strings to the array. This is what I observed: the 1) Array is created. 2) An object is inserted. 3) I observe the array object... and I see that it has the first object (index 0) AND there is a prototype property.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar: It's not weird at all. As I said in the answer, clearly someone's added `seek` to `Array.prototype`.

Comment: I don't think anybody is adding "seek". It turns out "seek" is a function that exists way up in the prototype chain. The weird thing is that this words in other git branches.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar: Something, somewhere, is absolutely adding `seek`, and doing so in a very pre-2009 way (2009 was when `defineProperty` was added, allowing non-enumerable properties to be added). As for "way up" in the prototype chain: It's on `Array.prototype` or `Object.prototype`. Those are the only two objects in an array's prototype chain.